# Css specify master css selector for many other selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to specify that all classes should be within the profile wrapper. Such as

```
.profileWrapper {
   .aPictureOfMe {
      width: 200px;
   }
   .listOfFriends {
      margin-right: 10px;
   }
}
```

So that it would be the equivalent of

```
.profileWrapper.aPictureOfMe {
   width: 200px;
}
.profileWrapper.listOfFriends {
   margin-right: 10px;
}
```

I am just looking for a way to save me all the typing and **would rather not use a compiler such as Less or Sass**. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: LESS is not a compiler, it's a way of writing CSS, then you must **compile** it to **standard** CSS for browser. You can do this by adding a **js** file to your website (not ideal), or by your code editor. Whenever you **SAVE** your LESS file in the editor (like Sublime Text or Visual Studio .NET), it will **generate** a CSS for you. That's it. [Ofcourse you must install a plugin for your editors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **No**, it is not possible to write CSS in that way without using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). *LESS and SASS were invented to save you all the typing, since vanilla CSS does not support nested rules.*

In addition to providing a solution to [nested rules](http://lesscss.org/#-nested-rules), by letting you use [mixins](http://lesscss.org/#-mixins), [variables](http://lesscss.org/#-variables), [functions](http://lesscss.org/#-functions), [operations](http://lesscss.org/#-operations) and [namespaces](http://lesscss.org/#-namespaces) they can save you a lot more typing than you are currently asking for, and they will help you to keep things organised and therefore easy to maintain.

As @NOX points out, you can either add a JavaScript file to your website which compiles it on the fly, or you can use a plugin for your IDE which compiles your LESS or SASS files as you save them in your code editor. The first option would have a negative impact on your web sites loading time, the last option doesn't have an impact on your web sites loading time at all.

With all these pro's there's only really one reason left for not using LESS or SASS, and that would be not wanting to pay for a plugin which compiles things for you. I'm using [Web Workbench by Mindscape](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) on Visual Studio, it works great, and there's a free version.

Answer (score 0):

Use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

---

```
// LESS
#header {
  h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  p { font-size: 12px;
    a { text-decoration: none;
      &:hover { border-width: 1px }
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
/* Compiled CSS */

#header h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#header p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#header p a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#header p a:hover {
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

---

### NOTE

LESS is not a compiler, it's a way of writing CSS.
Then you must **compile** it to **standard** CSS for browsers.
You can do this by adding a **js** file to your website (not ideal), or by your **code editor**.
Whenever you **SAVE** your LESS file in the editor (like Sublime Text or Visual Studio .NET),
it will generate a CSS for you.

- Ofcourse you must install a plugin for your editors.

Comment: I stated that I would rather not use a compiler, is that the only solution?

Comment: No, but you can compile it at server side with your own language (such as PHP) or with your **code editor** (like Sublime Text), and then use the compiled CSS in your project. There is no need to compile it at runtime when user is surfing your website.